# Editing hosts file - will removing default settings cause trouble?

Tags: linux, hosts, hosts-file, fqdn

I'm running a CentOS 5.4 machine and had trouble getting sendmail to work. After a bunch of researching, I found out that I needed to change my servers FQDN. `/etc/hosts` had the following:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain  
xx.xx.xx.xx  test
```

(the xx.xx.xx.xx is my server's real IP address, and 'test' is I believe the name of the machine)

I removed the above two lines and replaced it with:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx  mydomain.com  MyDomain
```

sendmail now works perfectly, but because I'm inexperienced with Linux and FQDNs, I'm not sure if changing this file will cause unexpected problems somewhere else. Web and FTP access seem unaffected, but I'm curious if any Linux gurus know if I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
xx.xx.xx.xx     test.mydomain.com test mydomain.com
```

Also check to see what your `/etc/sysconfig/network` says for the hostname value. That should either be `test` or `test.domain.com`.

Typically, you want to reboot or restart network services after making changes to the hostname or host file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My `/etc/sysconfig/network` has 'test' as the host, so that matches. Aside from restarting httpd, are there any other network services that need to be restarted?

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart httpd at all. When he (she?) says "network services" he means the network stack. On CentOS I believe that would be "service networking restart" (but it might be "service network restart")

Comment: `/sbin/service network restart`